# Highcharts scatter plot. Bad working 'hover' of points near the edge of plot

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

When scatter points placed on the edge of plot, 'hover' event triggered only when mouse is over a part of the point in the plot area. With small markers the user has to 'hunt for pixels' for tooltip.
Here is the sample:
http://jsfiddle.net/Efm4p/4/

```
$(function () {
var chart;

$(document).ready(function() {
    chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container',
            type: 'scatter',
        },
        xAxis:{
            min:0,
            max: 100},
        yAxis:{
            min:0,
            max:2,
            tickInterval:1,
            lineWidth:1
        },
        series: [{
            marker:{
                lineWidth:1,
                lineColor:'BBBBBB',
                radius:3
            },
            data: [{x: 10, y: 2}, {x: 0.5, y:1}, {x: 0, y: 1}, {x: 12, y: 2}, {x: 11, y: 2}]
        }]
    });
});  

});
```

In this example very hard to get a tooltip for point {x: 0, y: 1}.

I'm trying to set minPadding/maxPadding for axis, but they don't work when I set min/max clearly.
It is important to set min/max explicitly, because a real chart shows % form 0 to 100 by x-axis and categories by y-axis. Some of points have a 0% or 100% values by x-axis and belong for first or last category by y-axis.

**Upd:** My question is "How to make 'hover' working normal for points, placed on the edge of the plot?"

Comment: Okay, but where is your question? You cna set min: -5 to make some space on the left side, and add plotLine to highlight 0 value on xAxis.

Comment: 2Paweł Fus: I update my question.

Answer (score 0):

This is default behavior for scatter series - show tooltip only when hover marker. You can change series type to `line`, and set `lineWidth: 0`. That should work much better.

Only limit is that data for line/spline should be sorted ascending by x-values, and duplicates for the same x-value are not allowed. Simple adding sort to your data will resolve that issue.

```
(function() { 
    return [{x: 10, y: 2}, {x: 0.5, y:1}, {x: 0, y: 1}, {x: 12, y: 2}, {x: 21, y: 1}]
            .sort(function(a,b){ return a.x - b.x } );
})()
```

Combined example: http://jsfiddle.net/Efm4p/5/

Comment: Thank You for fast answer!  Sort makes it much better, but tooltip still showing only when mouse hovering a right half of the point (if x == 0).  I want no know, is it possible to trigger 'hover' when mouse over left half of the point without changing min/max or I should start to explore and modify the source code of highcharts.  P.S.: I'm sorry for my bad English!